# Shared folder on mac: mounted on ubuntu but not writable

Tags: network-shares, samba

I've got a mac (called 'maxw-hackbook') with a folder (called 'work') which i've shared, making it "read & write" by me, "staff" and everyone.  I've then mounted it to a folder on my ubuntu laptop, as follows:

```
#on ubuntu laptop
$ smbtree -s
WORKGROUP
\\MAXW-HACKBOOK         maxw-hackbook
    \\MAXW-HACKBOOK\IPC$            IPC Service (maxw-hackbook)
    \\MAXW-HACKBOOK\work            work

 $ sudo smbmount //MAX-HACKBOOK/work/ /mnt/hackbook-work -o ip=192.168.1.228,username=Max,password=passwordonmacbook,w
```

This has successfully mounted the "work" folder on the macbook to the /mnt/hackbook-work folder in ubuntu.  But, it's read-only, even though i've set the shared folder (on the mac) to be "read and write" by everybody.

I need to have write access to that folder on the mac.  Can anybody see what i've done wrong?

thanks, max

Comment: I assume you meant "MAXW-HACKBOOK" instead of "MAX-HACKBOOK", and that you used the "rw" mount option and not "w" as you wrote above?

Comment: You assume i know what i'm doing :)  I redid it with the right name, still no joy.  But then just realised that i need to set the file permissions on the folders in the mac as well.  I did `chmod -R a+w work` and that fixed it.  How was i even able to mount it with the wrong name (MAX-HACKBOOK), is what i'm wondering now.  Thanks!